# Django versions mixed up

Tags: python, django, version

I'm new with django, and having the following error with my admin page when I try to add an user:

```
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: DatabaseError at /admin/auth/user/add/
Exception Value: no such column: django_content_type.name
```

I tried to upgrade django, but it says that it is already on the last version, and when I try to delete it manualy, it says that I'm deleting 1.8.2 when the error page says it is 1.5.1... don't know why the versions are mixed, or how to fix it, thanks in advance!

PD:
Yes, I did all the migrates and syncdbs there is to do.

Comment: Do you run your website with the same Python version that you use `pip` with?

Comment: How do I check that? There are 2 versions of python on my computer btw, but I'm using 2.7.10 inside my virtualenv.

Comment: install **virtualenvwrapper** then simply **workon your_venv**

Comment: @AngelGuastaferro have you activated your virtualenv?

Comment: @AngelGuastaferro also, you can run `pip --version` to check which Python interpreter you use pip with and what is the directory pip installs packages to.